# Does Raspberry Pi 4 Model B has different Voltage for the different frequencies supported?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
gives the following frequency list as supported

600000 700000 800000 900000 1000000 1100000 1200000 1300000 1400000 1500000

We are able to set the core frequency to each of the above frequencies by setting the governor to userspace.

Checking the core voltage always returns the following value for each of those frequencies

vcgencmd measure_volts core
**volt=0.8625V**

Does it mean that we only have one voltage supported?

Comment: there's the `over_voltage` config.txt option that allows you to set voltage between 0.8V and 1.4V in 0.025V steps - as per "documentation" - https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md

Comment: This site https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2019/11/29/raspberry-pi-4-firmware-update-pi-4-now-runs-cooler-than-ever/ suggests the firmware released in October 2019 – Clocking and Load Step Firmware supports voltage change. sudo rpi-update  Git hash for the firmware version can upgrade/downgrade to a specific firmware revision. But, how do we figure out the Git Hash for the October 2019 – Clocking and Load Step Firmware